# FastAPI unit test returns 422

Tags: python, json, fastapi

I am new to python and FastAPI and writing some test code for FastAPI endpoints.
I have the following function for unit testing, but when I run it I get back status code 422.
Not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
    def test_create_event(self):
        my_date = datetime.date(2023, 6, 15)
        data = {'id': '1', 'title': 'Winter Cooking', 'host': 'Steven',
                'ingredients': ['Apples','Pumpkin','Pecans','Oats'], 
                'date': my_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'), 'participants': ['Steven','Kyle']}
        response = requests.post(self.url + '/events/', json=data)
        print("response=" + str(response.status_code))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

The Event class is defined the following way:

```
class Event(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    host: str
    ingredients: List[str] = []
    date: datetime
    participants: List[str] = []
```

My POST method that works is defined here:

```
# For event creation via POST
@events_router.post("/events/", status_code=201, response_model=Event)
def create_event(*, event_in: EventCreate) -> Event:
    """
    Create a new event (in memory only)
    """
    #change below to be based on global variable counter
    global counter
    new_entry_id = counter
    # TODO: change date to server-side data value
    event_entry = Event(
        id=new_entry_id,
        title=event_in.title,
        host=event_in.host,
        ingredients=event_in.ingredients,
        date=event_in.date,
        participants=event_in.participants
    )
    EVENTS.append(event_entry.dict())
    counter += 1

    return event_entry
```

Thanks for any advice

Update:

The EventCreate class:

```
class EventCreate(BaseModel):
    title: str
    host: str
    ingredients: List[str] = []
    date: datetime
    participants: List[str] = []
    submitter_id: int
```

I changed the code to the following:

```
def test_create_event(self):
        my_date = datetime.date(2023, 6, 15)
        data = {'title': 'Winter Cooking', 'host': 'Steven',
                'ingredients': ['Apples','Pumpkin','Pecans','Oats'], 
                'date': my_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'), 
                'participants': ['Steven','Kyle'], 'submitter_id': 1, }
        response = requests.post(self.url + '/events/', json=data)
        print("response=" + str(response.status_code))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

Still getting 422 error code

Comment: Your API expects a `EventCreate` in the request, what does that looks like?

Comment: btw. you shouldn't do a real requests in tests. Use TestClient (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/) or responses (https://pypi.org/project/responses/)

Comment: Added EventCreate to original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the debugger and found that it’s the date time format:
b’{“detail”:[{“loc”:[“body”,“date”],“msg”:“invalid datetime format”,“type”:“value_error.datetime”}]}’

I changed the values to ISO8601 format and viola it works.
Here is my new code:

```
def test_create_event(self):
        my_date = my_date = datetime.now(timezone.utc).replace(microsecond=0).astimezone().isoformat()
        print("my_date="+my_date)
        data = {'id': '1', 'title': 'Winter Cooking', 'host': 'Steven',
                'ingredients': ['Apples','Pumpkin','Pecans','Oats'], 
                'date': my_date, 'participants': ['Steven','Kyle']}
        response = requests.post(self.url + '/events/', json=data)
        print("response=" + str(response.status_code))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

Thanks for the help everyone!